# Browse a matrix

Tags: c#, matrix

I want to browse a matrix like these one :

[image: example of matrix I want to browse]

I want browse the first row, get the smallest number, then browse the row matching with the precedent smallest number.

Ex : I browse the A row : I browse the cell A,A , I get 0. I don't keep it (because it's 0) I browse the cell A,D I get 5. I keep it. I browse the cell A,G I get 8 but i don't keep it because it is superior to 5. I browse cell A,K and I get 4 I keep it (< 5).

For the moment it's ok, a simple loop is sufficient to do this. Then I want to browse the row K and if possible don't browse the cell K,A because I already browsed it when I browsed the row A.

Comment: At what point will your search through the matrix terminate?  So far it sounds like something that can be easily accomplished with two nested loops.

Comment: Is this a 2D array structure in C#? What code you have already? The verb "browse" also is confusing to me in this context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the solution I found :

```
    private static IEnumerable<int> ComputeMatrix(int[,] matrix)
    {
        // check args
        if (matrix.Rank != 2) { throw new ArgumentException("matrix should have a rank of 2"); }
        if (matrix.GetUpperBound(0) != matrix.GetUpperBound(1)) { throw new ArgumentException("matrix should have the same size");}

        // indice treated
        List<int> treatedIndex = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= matrix.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
        {
            if (treatedIndex.Count == matrix.GetUpperBound(0)) 
                break;

            // distance minimum between 2 points
            int distanceMin = Int32.MaxValue;

            // next iteration of index
            int nextI = i;

            // add the index to ignore in the next iteration
            int nextJ = -1;

            for (int j = 0; j <= matrix.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                if (treatedIndex.IndexOf(j) == -1)
                {
                    if (matrix[i, j] != 0 && matrix[i, j] < distanceMin)
                    {
                        distanceMin = matrix[i, j];
                        nextI = j;
                        nextJ = i;
                    }
                }
            }

            i = nextI - 1;
            treatedIndex.Add(nextJ);
            yield return distanceMin;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through an upper/lower half of the matrix? I assume a matrix is an array of int arrays.

```
var matrix = new int[][]{ ... };
int smallest = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < matrix.Length; j++)
    {
        int number = matrix[i][j];
        if (number != 0 && number < smallest)
            smallest = number;
    }
}
```

Although, I didn't quite get

> then browse the row matching with the precedent smallest number

part.